# Can't find location of undo *.tuf file

Tags: sql-server-2000

I run SQL Server 2000. Database is in standby mode. I have multiple files with MyDb.tuf name on a different drives. How may I know which one is in use?

Comment: Rename them? The one in use should be locked...

Comment: I can rename anyone of them. They are not locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the one with the most recent datetime stamp to be the one that is in use.